# How to add a custom field button to a field in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I looked through the developer blogs and I can only find ways to create a custom global form button or to replace a field with custom code.  I don't want to replace the field, I want to add a button beside a field.

Here's what I have in mind:

```
[Date Field][date_picker_button]   [time field][time_is_now]
```

The button I want to add is the `time_is_now`, allowing the user to populate the time field with the current time.

I have tried updating `custom/modules/Notes/metadata/quickcreatedefs.php` with:

```
array (
   'name' => 'billable_start_c',
    'label' => 'LBL_BILLABLE_START',
    'customCode' => '<button</button>',
   )
```

But this replaces the input field with the custom code.  I could just put in the stock code and then my custom code, but date fields use yui and a widget, so I'd prefer not to.

Is there anyway to do something like:

```
  'customCode' => '{default} <button></button>',
```

so that the default code gets output and then the custom code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use custom code if you can help it.   Either copy over the tpl to `custom/modules/[yourmodule]/tpls/[yourtemplate]` and code the bitton in there  or use an after_ui_frame hook and some js to insert you custom button into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new SugarField template, which will essentially allow you to create the markup for your field.  If you named your SugarField TimeIsNow, you could create a field with that type (instead of text,int, date or whatever).  You should take a look at some of the other SugarFields to see how they are formatted, but it's really just HTML.  When the field is set to that type, it pulls in that HTML template.  You can tie your JS to the onclick function.  Sugar is very easy to customize, so I definitely wouldn't get in the habit of solving all your customization needs this way...It's another way to look at it though.